# Google is not showing the English subdomain in the search results when searching for our domain name

Tags: google-search, search-engines, internationalization, language, search-results

We have a dual language news portal. We had changed domain name in December, 2017.

Nowadays, when we search for the domain name it only shows the "bn" language website.  Google doesn't show the "en" language website in the results. Before changing the domain name, Google showed both language URLs in the search results for that query.  What can we do to get both URLs show in the search results?

Domain name example: `www.example.com` and `www.en.example.com`. Now only `www.example.com` is displayed in the search results but not `www.en.example.com`.

Comment: Do you use hreflang tags on the home page to let Google know about the alternate page for different languages?

Comment: If you search for the English subdomain will it come up when you search for it directly?

Comment: Have you considered putting both languages onto subdomain and having the main domain be a "choose your language" page?

Answer (score 1):

Subdomains and domains are treated differently, often times as completely different entities.

If you want to rank your subdomain, you will potentially have to try and rank it separately from your main one.

I assume that you 301 redirected your previous domain to your new one. You should also probably be 301 redirecting all of your old english pages to your en.example.com pages as well if you haven't. By 301 redirecting those pages to your subdomain, you would have retained your indexing and link juice.

If your English pages have been deindexed at this point, the best thing you can do is to link to them from your current domain. Google will eventually crawl the links and index those pages. You can also 301 redirect to them from your other English pages if that's still an option. If Google still has your English pages indexed from the previous domain, if you can redirect them to their new URL on en.example.com, you should be able to retain your indexing.